# Read (and store) the current brightness for AC/DC before I change it

Tags: vb.net

I have made a Brightness Changer App in Visual Studio with vb.net project based on this article: [Dream.In.Code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/126/entry-596-set-the-brightness-of-a-laptop-through-vbnet/)

The app works perfectly but I'm stuck at one spot though, Just like this guy who left the comment in the article. The guy receives no reply, so I decided to post it here.

[Screenshot of the guy's comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvXrM.png) (If you cant see the image you can refer to the quotation below.)

> I'm using this on a Vista Home Premium Machine...works like a dream in
>   my app.
>
> I can set my brightness anywhere between 0 and 100%.
>
> I'm stuck at one spot though, I want to read (and store) the current
>   brightness for AC/DC before I change it. This will allow me to restore
>   the brightness when the application ends.
>
> MSDN suggests the WMIMonitorBrightness Class, but i have no clue how
>   to use it or what imports I'll need. Apparently the
>   IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS function is deprecated in Vista,
>   so what options do I have?
>
> I tried using QUERY_DISPLAY in the same manner as SET display, but got
>   stuck at the formation of 
>   `DeviceIoControl(pDisplay, IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS, _ 
>   Brightness, Marshal.SizeOf(Brightness), IntPtr.Zero, 0, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero) line`
>   
> and where do i get the &H number for 
>   `Const IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS As Integer =`
>   
> Please Help. Either show me how to pull data from IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS or WMIMonitorBrightness. A Vista-only application is fine for now...but I would like to expand it to XP eventually.
>
> ~Matthew

PS: I'm on Windows 8.1 OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example worked well for me:

http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmiscripts/vbscript/0067/

In .Net it's pretty much the same:

```
    Dim objWMIService As Object = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\WMI")

    Dim colItems As Object = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From WmiMonitorBrightness")

    For Each objItem As Object In colItems
        Debug.Print("Active:" & objItem.Active)
        Debug.Print("CurrentBrightness:" & objItem.CurrentBrightness)
        Debug.Print("InstanceName:" & objItem.InstanceName)
        Debug.Print("Level:" & Join(objItem.Level))
        Debug.Print("Levels:" & objItem.Levels)
        Debug.Print("")
        Debug.Print("########")
        Debug.Print("")
    Next
```

Or if you prefer Strict On, import Microsoft WMI Scripting V1.2 Library and then:

```
    Dim objWMIService As WbemScripting.SWbemServicesEx = DirectCast(GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\WMI"), WbemScripting.SWbemServicesEx)

    Dim colItems As WbemScripting.SWbemObjectSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From WmiMonitorBrightness")

    For Each objItem As WbemScripting.SWbemObject In colItems
        Debug.Print("Active:" & objItem.Properties_.Item("Active").Value.ToString)
        Debug.Print("CurrentBrightness:" & objItem.Properties_.Item("CurrentBrightness").Value.ToString)
        Debug.Print("InstanceName: " & objItem.Properties_.Item("InstanceName").Value.ToString)
        Debug.Print("Level:" & Join(DirectCast(objItem.Properties_.Item("Level").Value, Object())))
        Debug.Print("Levels: " & objItem.Properties_.Item("Levels").Value.ToString)
        Debug.Print("")
        Debug.Print("########")
        Debug.Print("")
    Next
```